# Ruby on Rails Model.find generates a MySQL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Product model and it has many categories with a has_many :through association

In my controller I am trying to do a find by with categories.category but it comes up with a mysql error.

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['categories.category_id = ?', @category.id ])
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please provide us with more details: What error ? What code breaks ?

Comment: Can someone edit this with some additional code?  Something indicating that he has `class Product; has_many :categories; end` and `class Category; belongs_to :product; end` and then `Product.find` instead of `Model.find`.  That would seem to make the question more generic while still meeting the spirit of the question (at least how I understand it from the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing you're `find` on the `Product` model, you're either going to need to remove the `categories.` part of your `:conditions` statement, or add a `:joins => :categroies` to your finder.

Some more help would certainly narrow down the problem, however.